# Приложение для сборки приложений

Tags: android, app

Всем привет! Хочу сделать в своем приложении возможность создать... приложение :) Шаблон единый меняться будет только папкa assets и package. Как такое вообще можно реализовать?

Спасибо!

Comment: У меня так реализована автоматизированная сборка: есть сервер, есть репозиторий на GitHub. На сервере установлен минимально необходимый Android SDK, также настроен вебсервер. На вебформе можно выбрать ассеты и версию приложения. Это передается в php скрипт, который синхронизирует код с гитхаба, правит нужные части кода, а потом запускает скрипт сборки. После сборки перемещает созданный APK файл в директорию веб-сервера, давая возможность скачать собранный файл. Если интересует такой метод и есть необходимые ресурсы, то могу поделиться скриптом сборки

Comment: @Никита Васильченко, к сожалению нет) Сборка апк должна быть в самом приложении :) без серверов, все локально. Я вот думаю, мне в папке res нужны лишь иконки, а разметок, стилей и всего прочего не будет. java кода вообще не будет. Выходит, все что мне нужно, это манифест и assets + подпись. package можно прямо в манифесте писать, с assets трудностей не будет, как подписывать программно, думаю изучу. Потом кидаю все это дело в zip без сжатия и переименовываю в apk.